# LifecycleException when deploying

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I imported an project and try to deploy on the tomcat and error occurred.
The eclipse jre environment is

> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home

and tomcat java home is

> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/jre

```
    EVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/JuBenHunter]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/JuBenHunter]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> /subsystem/*.jsp in filter mapping
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.validateFilterMap(StandardContext.java:3199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addFilterMap(StandardContext.java:3148)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.configureContext(WebXml.java:1343)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1357)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:889)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5479)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

Nov 17, 2016 8:09:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:693)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1130)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

Nov 17, 2016 8:09:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:693)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1130)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more
```

The web.xml is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">
    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingfilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>common.filter.EncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>gbk</param-value>
        </init-param>

    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingfilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>userfileter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>common.filter.UserFilter</filter-class>

    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>userfileter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/subsystem/*.jsp</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>userfileter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*.do</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>config</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>3</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>detail</param-name>
            <param-value>3</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>config</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/struts-config-comm.xml,
                /WEB-INF/struts-config-base.xml,
                /WEB-INF/struts-config-hr.xml,
                /WEB-INF/struts-config-talent.xml,
                /WEB-INF/struts-config-sale.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>



    <!-- 配置数据库链接池 -->
    <display-name>proxool</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletConfigurator</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.configuration.ServletConfigurator
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>xmlFile</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/proxool.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Admin</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.admin.servlet.AdminServlet
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <description>This is the description of my J2EE component</description>
    <display-name>This is the display name of my J2EE component</display-name>
    <servlet-name>JsonServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>common.servlet.JsonServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Admin</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webadmin</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JsonServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/JsonServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this `url-pattern`

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>userfileter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*.do</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

with

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>userfileter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```